# Orange doesnot Load when I ugraded from Windows 7 to 8.1 (64 bit)

Tags: windows, orange

I was using orange effectively with windows 7. But as soon as I upgraded to 8.1 (64) it would not run any more. I have installed fresh versions several times but it would not run. The icons will show though but the application will neither load nor run.

Comment: Welcome to S.O. Please describe exacly what you did so far and where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

A part of Orange is in C++, so it's compiled to a DLL which needs to be compatible with Python. Orange installs Python itself unless it's already installed. Did you by any chance already have a 64-bit Python? The official Orange binary only runs on 32-bits, so it requires 32-bit Python. If these assumptions are correct, you will have to either switch to 32-bit Python, build Orange on 64-bits yourself or find a pre-compiled on one of the sites like http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#orange, I guess.

Otherwise, start Orange with "-l 4" option and you'll get a lot of output during startup.